# Can't step into an async method located in a release build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, task-parallel-library

It looks like it isn't possible to step into an async method if it is located in a assembly build in release mode.

I have created very simple example for testing this.

```
var sleep = new Sleep();
await sleep.SleepALittleAsync();
```

The `Sleep` class is located in another assembly and if I build it in debug mode everything is fine and I can easily step into `SleepALittleAsync`. If I build it in release mode it jump over my async method.
I have experienced with removing optimization and also have symbols file located, but without any luck.
If I have synchronously call it will also work. My debugger is setup with "just my code" unchecked.

Anyone who knows some tricks?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17677195/5062791

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate as I can easily debug as long as I'm not using async/await.

Comment: It's a partial duplication, the linked thread explains why this happens. The build is optimized in Release mode, whereas Debug outputs the PDB's. See the updated question in the linked post, primarily where it says "Just my Code".

Comment: It's a duplicate. The accepted answer talks about things that you "may" have problems with, and the limited things you can more reliably do. We could just add "may not be able to step into the state machines of an `async` method" to that list.
To add a little bit more, the state machines produced are one of the things particularly different between Debug and Release. In at least some versions they aren't even the same in terms of whether they're value or reference types, because value types are generally a better idea for performance for them, ...

Comment: ... making the implementations debuggable has more impact on actual field size etc. too, so there's good reason to lay them out differently if they aren't designed to be debuggable.