# HOWTO: Debug remotely an ASP.NET MVC release build in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, release, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging, asp.net-4.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC application in C# that was recently deployed in production on release mode.
The release has been published from visual studio 2019 Community with following options enabled:

- Optimize code
- Debug information: full

pdb files are correctly deployed in the web server.

**Screenshots**:

[image]

[image]

Now I am trying to debug it remotely so in the web server where app is deployed I have launched visual studio remote tools, msvsmon.exe

[image]

Then from Visual Studio I have attached to a process (I have attached to 3 processes w3wp.3xe - ids 16680, 14728 and 7732 - since application pool is configured with maximum processes=3,that is, web garden):

[image]

Also, I am wondering why process 7732 appears as managed typed and the rest of processes as x64.... Why? After that I am trying to put a breakpoint, but it seems it does not work:

[image]

So What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Release mode is not a good configuration for debugging a project. Just as [Hans said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675226/cannot-debug-application-in-release-mode-even-with-debugtype-full), So my suggestion is that, 1) disable `Just My Code` option. 2) when you attach the process, select the Managed Type 3) add the remote server's pdb files into `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`Symbols`.add the remote server's bin folder as a symbol file location.

Comment: When you remote debug the process, please enter Debug-->Windows-->Modules and check if the pdb file is loaded.